# Как остановить MediaPlayer при смене страницы в адаптере ViewPager

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Сделал слайдер изображений с озвучкой, к каждой картинке - свой аудиофайл. Запуск и пауза при нажатии на картинку. Реализацию сделал в адаптере Viewpager'а - по другому не додумался. Теперь вопрос - как остановить воспроизведение аудиофайла при смене item_view (то есть при перелистывании на другую страницу). Вот код адаптера:

```
    public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        Context ctx;
        ArrayList<String> pagesFiles;
        ArrayList<String> soundsFiles;
        String folderB;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> pagesFiles, ArrayList<String> soundsFiles, String folderB) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.pagesFiles = pagesFiles;
        this.soundsFiles = soundsFiles;
        this.folderB = folderB;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pagesFiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
        final String soundPath = String.valueOf(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(folderB));
        final Uri souF = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath, nameS));
//        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, souF);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MyPlayer.getMp(ctx, souF);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflatter = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert layoutInflatter != null;
        View item_view = layoutInflatter.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        File imgFile = new File(pagesFiles.get(position));
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            container.addView(item_view);
        }
        item_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.pause();
            }
        }
        });

        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

Попробовал сделать медиаплеер статическим, но проблема остается. Вот код класса MyPlayer

```
public class MyPlayer {
    public static MediaPlayer mp;
    Context cont;
    Uri soundUri;

    public MyPlayer(Context cont, Uri soundUri) {
        this.cont = cont;
        this.soundUri = soundUri;
    }

    public static MediaPlayer getMp(Context cont, Uri soundUri) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(cont, soundUri);
        return mp;
    }

}
```

И дополнил код ViewPager

```
public class SliderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
/*
 * Читаем json и создаем из него объект книги bookFiles
 */
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        int bookId = GetBookId();
        String fileName = "book_" + bookId + ".json";
        String gsResult = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileName);
        BookFiles bookFiles = gson.fromJson(gsResult, BookFiles.class);

        String folderB = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
        /*
        Получаем из объекта bookFiles массивы путей к файлам книги
         */
        ArrayList<String> pagesFiles = bookFiles.getPagesPath();
        ArrayList<String> soundsFiles = bookFiles.getSoundsPath();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
        adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this, pagesFiles, soundsFiles, folderB);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        //слушаем номер слайда при перелистывании
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                final MediaPlayer mp = MyPlayer.mp;
                if (ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                } else {

                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public int GetBookId() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int bookId = intent.getIntExtra("bookId", 1);
//        Log.d(TAG, "You read book №" + bookId);
        return bookId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В событии пролистывания `ViewPager:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if(ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE == state){
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.pause();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: if else одинаковое условие, это вызывает ошибку. После исправления не срабатывает остановка

Comment: Они одинаковые потому что в первом случае прокрутка вправо, else соответственно если прокрутка влево, и условие срабатывает только в случае если плеер при прокрутки в одну из сторон находится в состоянии воспроизведения.

Comment: Если убрать второе условие, то плеер будет переходить в состояние паузы только в случае прокрутки вправо. У меня все прекрасно работает, покажите логи, какую это ошибку вызывает.

Comment: пока не могу, пишу с другого компьютера. Про условия понял. Когда пробовал, то пришлось в activity определить экземпляр MediaPlayer, это нормально? Хотя сам mp создается в адаптере. Иначе вылетал NullExeption. Дело в том, что перелистывать слайд можно и без запуска аудиофайла, как раз этот вариант и вызывал фаталь

Comment: Сделайте медиаплеер статическим

Comment: не получается у меня. Посмотрите пожалуйста код, где я неправильно пишу

Comment: @Вячеслав Покажите то, что в логах

Comment: B логах все нормально, нет ошибок